# Problema al modificar tabla en postgresql mediante python

Tags: python, postgresql, tkinter

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos y estoy intentando realizar un control de acceso mediante python en una base de datos en postfresql utilizando la librería de TKinter.

El problema con el que me encuentro es que no sé como modificar la tabla para introducir la hora a la que se pasa tarjeta.

Puedo realizar consultas mediante este trozo de código.

```
def getbarcode (self):
    conexion = psycopg2.connect()
    cursor01 = conexion.cursor()
    cursor01.execute('select * from ControlAcceso where codigollave =' + str(self.dato.get()))
    consulta = cursor01.fetchall()
    print(consulta)
```

De aquí es de donde obtengo la referencia para cada usuario, es un lector de RF.

```
    str(self.dato.get())
```

En las label6 y label7 la fecha y la hora actuales.

```
    self.label5.configure(text=datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
    
    self.label7.configure(text=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M'))
   
    cursor01.close()
```

Pero ahora no sé como realizar una modificación en mi tabla de postgresql con la hora a la que se hace la consulta.

- EDITADO*

Tras los consejos he utilizado estas dos variantes:

Variante 1:

```
def getbarcode (self):
    conexion = psycopg2.connect( database = 'ControlAcceso', user = 'postgres', password = 'Color1984' )
    cursor01 = conexion.cursor()
    cursor01.execute('select * from ControlAcceso where codigollave =' + str(self.dato.get()))
    cursor01.execute('alter table ControlAcceso alter column Entrada set current_date where codigollaves =' + str(self.dato.get()))        consulta = cursor01.fetchall()
    print(consulta)
```

Variante 2:

```
def getbarcode (self):
    conexion = psycopg2.connect( database = 'ControlAcceso', user = 'postgres', password = 'Color1984' )
    cursor01 = conexion.cursor()
    cursor01.execute('select * from ControlAcceso where codigollave =' + str(self.dato.get()))
    cursor01.execute('update Entrada set current_date where codigollaves =' + str(self.dato.get()))
    consulta = cursor01.fetchall()
    print(consulta)
```

Pero en ambas me da un error de sintaxis. La conexión a la base de datos la hace bien, pero al intentar modificar la tabla de la base de datos me da error.

Comment: Alter table sirve para modificar la tabla en sí, no los registros. Para eso deberías de usar [update](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-update/)

Comment: ¿UPDATE aunque el registro este vacío?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta? Vacío en que sentido? Todo es null, todo es cadena vacía...?

Comment: Perdona, me refería a que ¿aunque la columna en la que quiero introducir el dato esté vació utilizo UPDATE en lugar de ALTERE?

De todos modos me sigue dando un error de SyntaxError que no consigo comprender por qué falla.

Comment: Exactamente. Sin embargo, esesyntax error es raro. Podrias editar la pregunta y agregar tu nuevo intento de resolver el problema y el error que da por favor?

Comment: El error de sintaxis que te da, puede ser por el `altere` que utilizas, en lugar de `alter`

Comment: Disculpad, he estado unos días enfermo y no he podido responder. Lo lamento mucho, he probado las dos soluciones que me ofrecéis en los comentario y no he conseguido arreglarlo. He editado la pregunta para que sea más sencillo seguir el caso. Gracias y disculpas.

Comment: ¡Un repasito por la sintaxis de `ALTER TABLE` y `UPDATE` no te vendría nada mal! (Sin importar si es PostgreSQL o el motor que sea, es SQL estándar). ¿Qué columna estás queriendo modificar? `UPDATE la_columna_en_cuestión SET current_date`: ¿pero qué columna? _current_date_ sería el **valor**. ¿Está esa columna en la base de datos? ¿O lo que querés hacer es agregar esa nueva columna a la tabla, e insertar un valor por defecto? Por último, pon el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo.